# How can I capture dependancies used by a subset of code in a python source file?

Tags: python, module, abstract-syntax-tree

Say I have the following code in code.py:

```
from foo import bar
from foo2 import bar2
from foo3 import wrapper

class A(bar):
    def m1(self,x):
        return wrapper(x)
```

Then I have a reference to an A object in the var "obj" and I get the code for that object like so:

```
c = inspect.getsource(obj)
```

which returns:

```
class A(bar):
    pass
```

I need to be able to parse "inspect.getsource(obj)" to know that the A class depends on the "from foo import bar" and "from foo3 import wrapper" at the top of the file returned by "inspect.getsourcefile(obj)".

How can I achieve this?

The only way to get close that I know of is by using [modulefinder](http://docs.python.org/library/modulefinder.html), but it runs on the whole file and would give me all three imports, not just the one used by the code of interest.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Edit: updated definition
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if an object or a class inherits from a class in another module, using `inspect` is probably the wrong way. You can instead use something like that:

```py
for base in A.__bases__:
  print "A depends on module %s" % base.__module__
```

Or for an object:

```py
for base in (obj.__class__,) + obj.__class__.__bases__:
  print "obj depends on module %s" % base.__module__
```

Comment: I updated the example in my code.  I need to be able to detect that "from foo3 import wrapper" was used as well.

Comment: @user319862: You need to [walk the AST](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html), but I doubt the correct resolution of the names can be done at source-inspection time, which you seem to want to.